# Point Light not rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, lighting

I'm trying to render a couple point lights in my scene, but having trouble getting the actual lights to illuminate. The only light I got to work is a directional light which lights up the scene initially:

[image: Directional Light with no Point Light rendering]

Where the two rocks are displayed are the same positions as the two point lights. I've toyed around with the diffuse, color and attenuation values, but got the same results. But when changed the ambiance of either light, the color changed:

[image: Directional Light with Ambient Intensity]

My calculations within GLSL are correct and my uniforms are read correctly as well. But somehow I lost my diffuse intensity. `m_pointLight[0].DiffuseIntensity` doesn't registers a change, but if the commented `AmbientIntensity` is used, the scene is tinted red.

```
m_scale += 0.0057f;

// changing the value makes scene red
m_pointLight[0].AmbientIntensity = 0.5f;
// changing the value does nothing 
m_pointLight[0].DiffuseIntensity = 1.5f; 
// light color is red
m_pointLight[0].Color = glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
// position of light (same as rock) 
m_pointLight[0].Position = glm::vec3(3.0f, 1.0f, FieldDepth * (cosf(m_scale) + 1.0f) / 2.0f);
// Light decay
m_pointLight[0].Attenuation.Linear = 0.01f;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Not a real answer** but I figured out part of what my problem was:

The problem was the angle I was looking from. Something is quite wrong with my code. I set my **camera position to (0, 100, 75)** originally. After moving the a small block of code to where I I set my perspective and other uniforms, a bit of light started to show from the point light. The problem then was when the two rocks moved, closer to the center of the floor, the point light of the first rock started to glow red. Same goes for the second rock, but it was set to blue. But as the rocks moved closer to the camera, the colors faded gradually until it appeared off. Then when it moved back to the center, the colors gradually got brighter to full capacity.

So then I was thinking this may have to do with the angle that I'm at. So from the **camera position (0, 100, 75)**, I decided to look from the complete opposite end of the floor **(-75 for the z-axis).** And this is what I got:

[image]

The only problem remaining is that depending on where the camera is, the point light closest to the camera doesn't show (other than on the underside of the closest rock). The bottom right image is the only one displaying all lights correctly:

[image]

***If some could explain what is going on, it would be greatly appreciated.***

Comment: maybe you didn't set the position of the light correctly

Comment: @ratchetfreak I hard-coded the lights position and added an actual camera so I can see whats happening in real-time. As I move around just like in the pictures, I get the same results. The red and blue stay to the left and right of the view of camera instead of staying in place.

Comment: then you set the light in *camera space* instead of *object space*